# Перегрузка операторов ввода-вывода и ==

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

По заданию есть

```
class Owner {
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    char* phone;
public:
Owner() {
        name = new char[12];
        strcpy(name, "noname");
        surname = new char[12];
        strcpy(surname, "nosurname");
        phone = new char[12];
        strcpy(phone, "nophone");
    };
```

... и тд...
Надо перегрузить операторы ввода-вывода и == по всем полям Owner.
Внутри public:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Owner& o) {
    out << o.name << " " << o.surname << " " << o.phone << endl;
    return out;
};
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Owner& o) {
    in >> o.name >> o.surname >> o.phone;
    return in;
};
friend bool operator==(const Owner &a, const Owner &b) {
    return (a.name == b.name && 
        a.surname == b.surname &&
        a.phone == b.phone);
};
```

В main():

```
Owner o1, o2("ABCD", "EFGH", "1234"), o3;
cout << ">> O3:" << endl;
cin >> o3;
cout << "<< O3:" << endl;
cout << o3;
cout << "O1 == O3:" << endl;
if (o1 == o3)
{
    cout << "O1 == O3" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "O1 != O3" << endl;
}
```

Постоянно выводит "O1 != O3", что бы я не вводил, даже когда noname nosurname nophone
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

```
a.name == b.name
```

Это - сравнение **указателей**, которые, конечно же, разные у разных объектов...

С-строки сравнивают с помощью функций наподобие [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: вы большие молодцы!